# Generating numbers from probabilities in csv file in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, probability, probability-distribution

I have an excel file with different cases and about 75 events for each case. There is a probability of each event happening given each case. So the excel file looks like this:

```
       event1  event2 ...   event75    

case1  0.0343  0.0234 ...   0.1194

case2  0.0924  0.0532 ...   0.0023
```

I want to generate a random number in python, ranging from 0 to 75 with the probabilities of the given case. When I worked with cases with only 2 events that could occur, I used a code like this:

```
excel_cases = pd.read_csv('/.../cases.csv')

def event_probabilities(case):
event_probability = excel_cases.loc[excel_cases['Case'] == case, 'event1'].values[0]
return event_probability

event1_probability = event_probabilities("case1")
np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 3), p=[event1_probability, (1 - event1_probability)])
# can also do an event2_probability instead of 1-event1_probability
```

However when the range of events get bigger I don't know what would be a more efficient way of doing this. Thanks for the help.

*Not same as the other question as I'm getting the probabilities from Excel

Comment: You have 75 events, but 76 return values (0-75); what is the extra one?

Comment: I thought when range(0,75) it doesn't include 75 so it is 75 values, 0 to 74

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are going to 4 decimals of precision right? So what you could do is get a random number between 0 and 9999:

```
from random import randint
randomNum = randint(0,9999))
```

And then multiply each probability by 10000 and set up a bunch of elif statements for each switch. So if event_1 has a probability of 0.0045 and event 2 has a probability of .0100, the elif would look something like this.

```
if randomNum < 45:
    event_1()
elif randomNum > 45 && randomNum < 145:
    event_2()
..........
```

and so on. This shouldn't require anywhere near as many calls to random. Though setting it up might not be trivial.

Comment: It would take a long time to do this, it's not very practical, just like the method I used. I am looking for a simpler way, don't know if there is one.

Comment: It wouldn't take too long if you generated the code programmatically, but that is a whole different task all together.